# Is there a way to set a default color for the un-selected boxes in heatmap in dc.js when crossfilter is applied?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

When i select a cell in the Heatmap, the surrounding cells turn into a "grey" color which is defined in the DC CSS styling file. When the crossfilter is applied between two heatmaps the remaining un matched cells in the other maps turn to a respective color depending on the data set uploaded i'm assuming. Is there a way to set this to the default "grey" color as in the first selected Heatmap

[image: Lime green should turn into Grey color]

```
          var data = [
         {
      [
   {
 "x54": -0.882989,
"x1": -0.696828,
 "row": 1,
 "column": 1
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.876465,
 "x1": -0.644057,
 "row": 1,
 "column": 2
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.826277,
 "x1": -0.307709,
 "row": 1,
 "column": 3
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.72772,
 "x1": -0.197103,
 "row": 1,
 "column": 4
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.439598,
 "x1": -0.41709,
 "row": 1,
 "column": 5
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.153818,
 "x1": -0.663918,
 "row": 1,
 "column": 6
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.083729,
 "x1": -0.832624,
 "row": 1,
 "column": 7
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.185048,
 "x1": -1.058972,
 "row": 1,
 "column": 8
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.74784,
 "x1": -0.79349,
 "row": 1,
 "column": 9
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.880683,
 "x1": -0.678627,
 "row": 1,
 "column": 10
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.222528,
 "x1": -0.234477,
 "row": 2,
 "column": 1
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.201995,
 "x1": -0.22677,
 "row": 2,
 "column": 2
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.047466,
 "x1": -0.176348,
 "row": 2,
 "column": 3
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.883628,
 "x1": -0.195366,
 "row": 2,
 "column": 4
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.554343,
 "x1": -0.406823,
 "row": 2,
 "column": 5
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.188488,
 "x1": -0.74227,
 "row": 2,
 "column": 6
 },
 {
"x54": -0.153185,
 "x1": -1.211219,
 "row": 2,
 "column": 7
  },
 {
 "x54": -0.123571,
 "x1": -1.544932,
 "row": 2,
 "column": 8
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.307304,
 "x1": -1.222773,
 "row": 2,
 "column": 9
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.760703,
 "x1": -0.794464,
 "row": 2,
 "column": 10
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.787903,
 "x1": 0.53784,
 "row": 3,
 "column": 1
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.759356,
 "x1": 0.456399,
 "row": 3,
 "column": 2
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.597539,
 "x1": -0.003567,
 "row": 3,
 "column": 3
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.494041,
 "x1": -0.208856,
  "row": 3,
 "column": 4
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.203471,
 "x1": -0.276973,
 "row": 3,
 "column": 5
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.237502,
 "x1": -0.613778,
 "row": 3,
 "column": 6
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.043425,
 "x1": -1.219936,
 "row": 3,
 "column": 7
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.157964,
 "x1": -1.560531,
 "row": 3,
 "column": 8
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.109837,
 "x1": -1.596408,
 "row": 3,
 "column": 9
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.313007,
 "x1": -1.216265,
 "row": 3,
 "column": 10
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.848956,
 "x1": 0.711575,
 "row": 4,
 "column": 1
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.786463,
 "x1": 0.516668,
 "row": 4,
 "column": 2
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.66119,
 "x1": -0.071153,
 "row": 4,
 "column": 3
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.626694,
 "x1": -0.207817,
 "row": 4,
 "column": 4
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.277511,
 "x1": -0.107304,
 "row": 4,
 "column": 5
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.285612,
 "x1": 0.301386,
 "row": 4,
 "column": 6
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.566092,
 "x1": -0.054815,
 "row": 4,
 "column": 7
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.250711,
 "x1": -0.731451,
 "row": 4,
 "column": 8
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.011755,
 "x1": -1.239403,
 "row": 4,
 "column": 9
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.056915,
 "x1": -1.204161,
 "row": 4,
 "column": 10
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.227091,
 "x1": 0.295195,
 "row": 5,
 "column": 1
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.034244,
 "x1": 0.36743,
 "row": 5,
 "column": 2
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.965926,
 "x1": 0.2263,
  "row": 5,
 "column": 3
 },
 {
 "x54": -1.044771,
 "x1": -0.037899,
 "row": 5,
 "column": 4
 },
 {
 "x54": -0.352724,
 "x1": 0.032479,
 "row": 5,
 "column": 5
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.829276,
 "x1": 0.548374,
 "row": 5,
 "column": 6
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.980084,
 "x1": 0.609911,
 "row": 5,
 "column": 7
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.836985,
 "x1": 0.39424,
 "row": 5,
 "column": 8
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.433473,
 "x1": 0.266364,
 "row": 5,
 "column": 9
 },
 {
 "x54": 0.002185,
 "x1": 0.946293,
 "row": 5,
 "column": 10
    }
   ];
         var ndx = crossfilter (data);
var  runDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return [+d.row, +d.column]; }),
  runGroup = runDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.x54; });

var  runDim1 = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return [+d.row, +d.column]; }),
  runGroup1 = runDim1.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.x1; });

         chart
.width(45 * 20 + 80)
.height(45 * 5 + 40)
.dimension(runDim1)
.group(runGroup1)
.keyAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[0]; })
.valueAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[1]; })
.colorAccessor(function(d) { return +d.value; })
.title(function(d) {
    return "Run:   " + d.key[0] + "\n" +
           "Expt:  " + d.key[1] + "\n" +
           "Speed: " + (299000 + d.value) + " km/s";})         
 .colors(['#000080', '#00008b', '#000097', '#0000a3', '#0000ae', '#0000ba', '#0000c6', '#0000d1', '#0000dd', '#0000e9', '0000f5', '#0000ff', '#0000ff', '#0006ff', '#0011ff', '#001bff', '#0025ff', '#0030ff', '#003aff', '#0044ff', '#00fff', '#0059ff', '#0063ff', '#006dff', '#0078ff', '#0082ff', '#008cff', '#0097ff', '#00a1ff', '#00abff', '#00b6f', '#00c0ff', '#00caff', '#00d5ff', '#00dffc', '#03e9f4', '#0bf3ec', '#14fee3', '#1cffdb', '#24ffd3', '#2cffca', '#35ffc2', '#3dffba', '#45ffb1', '#4effa9', '#56ffa1', '#5eff98', '#67ff90', '#6fff88', '#77ff80', '#80ff77', '#8ff6f', '#90ff67', '#98ff5e', '#a1ff56', '#a9ff4e', '#b1ff45', '#baff3d', '#c2ff35', '#caff2c', '#d3ff24', '#dbff1c', '#e3ff14', '#ecff0b', '#f4f903', '#fcef00', '#ffe600', '#ffdc00', '#ffd300', '#ffc900', '#ffc000', '#ffb600', '#ffad00', '#ffa300', '#ff9900', '#ff9000', '#ff8600', '#ff7d00', '#ff7300', '#ff6a00', '#ff6000', '#ff5700', '#ff4d00', '#ff4400', '#ff3a00', '#ff3100', '#ff2700', '#ff1d00', '#ff1400', '#f50a00', '#e90100', '#dd0000', '#d0000', '#c60000', '#ba0000', '#ae0000', '#a30000', '#970000', '#8b0000','#800000'])
.calculateColorDomain();

          chart1
.width(45 * 20 + 80)
.height(45 * 5 + 40)
.dimension(runDim)
.group(runGroup)
.keyAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[0]; })
.valueAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[1]; })
.colorAccessor(function(d) { return +d.value; })
.title(function(d) {
    return "Run:   " + d.key[0] + "\n" +
           "Expt:  " + d.key[1] + "\n" +
           "Speed: " + (299000 + d.value) + " km/s";})
 .colors(['#000080', '#00008b', '#000097', '#0000a3', '#0000ae', '#0000ba', '#0000c6', '#0000d1', '#0000dd', '#0000e9', '0000f5', '#0000ff', '#0000ff', '#0006ff', '#0011ff', '#001bff', '#0025ff', '#0030ff', '#003aff', '#0044ff', '#00fff', '#0059ff', '#0063ff', '#006dff', '#0078ff', '#0082ff', '#008cff', '#0097ff', '#00a1ff', '#00abff', '#00b6f', '#00c0ff', '#00caff', '#00d5ff', '#00dffc', '#03e9f4', '#0bf3ec', '#14fee3', '#1cffdb', '#24ffd3', '#2cffca', '#35ffc2', '#3dffba', '#45ffb1', '#4effa9', '#56ffa1', '#5eff98', '#67ff90', '#6fff88', '#77ff80', '#80ff77', '#8ff6f', '#90ff67', '#98ff5e', '#a1ff56', '#a9ff4e', '#b1ff45', '#baff3d', '#c2ff35', '#caff2c', '#d3ff24', '#dbff1c', '#e3ff14', '#ecff0b', '#f4f903', '#fcef00', '#ffe600', '#ffdc00', '#ffd300', '#ffc900', '#ffc000', '#ffb600', '#ffad00', '#ffa300', '#ff9900', '#ff9000', '#ff8600', '#ff7d00', '#ff7300', '#ff6a00', '#ff6000', '#ff5700', '#ff4d00', '#ff4400', '#ff3a00', '#ff3100', '#ff2700', '#ff1d00', '#ff1400', '#f50a00', '#e90100', '#dd0000', '#d0000', '#c60000', '#ba0000', '#ae0000', '#a30000', '#970000', '#8b0000','#800000'])
.calculateColorDomain();

  dc.renderAll();
```

Comment: Previously asked here (but the answer is incomplete): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580748/dc-js-heatmap-deselected-colors I'd ask the same question I commented there: do you want all zeros to display as grey (including zeros directly from the data), or just zeros that result from filtering?

Comment: In my case just the zeros resulting from filtering. I would like it to be the same shade as defined in the dc.css i.e (#ccc) instead of picking the first color defined in the array of colors. Ex:  .colors(['#000080', '#000092', '#0000a4']). An explanation to the first question would be helpful. Thanks in advance @Gordon

Comment: The lime green color which appears on applying the crossfilter should also be grey i.e (#ccc).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue where I wanted my zero values to be a certain color while anything else to fall on the color scale. I came across this page on default values for a d3 color scale and it worked nicely:

[d3 quantile scale force first quantile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457643/d3-quantile-scale-force-first-quantile)

The idea here is to create a function which wraps a d3 color scale. On a zero value return the default color otherwise pass the value to the internal scale and return the resulting value.

After creating the wrapper function, pass it into `.colors()` instead of the array of colors

Note that you may need to set the domain and range yourself on the function like this:

`colorScale.domain = colorScaleInternal.domain;`

`colorScale.range = colorScaleInternal.range;`